# mat-accordion is lagging when calling angular component in it recursively

Tags: angular, recursion, tree, components, angular8

I'm calling a component recursively in accordion to show tree like structure.

The code is working for short input but it is lagging on recursive calls for nested data

It is just like a json tree.

```
//sample.component.html
<app-tree [input]="data"></app-tree>


//tree.component.html

    <mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle="true" (click)="toggleTree($event, input)">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                <mat-icon>{{input.buttonName}}</mat-icon>
                {{input.key}}
            </mat-panel-title>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <ul class="main-obj">   // tried *ngIf here
             <div class="obj-list" *ngFor="let item of input.value; trackBy: trackChanges">
                <li>
                  {{item.key}}: {{item.value}}
                </li>
                <li style="list-style: none; margin-left: -40px;">
                    <app-tree [input]="item"></app-tree>
                </li>
            </div>
         </ul>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
    </mat-accordion>

//tree.component.ts

    import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
    import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-tree',
      templateUrl: './tree.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./tree.component.css']
    })

    export class TreeComponent implements OnInit {
        @Input() input: any;

        @Output() click = new EventEmitter();

        constructor(){}

        ngOnInit(){
        }

        toggleTree(event, toggleButton) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            if(toggleButton.buttonName == 'add')  
                toggleButton.buttonName = 'remove';
            else
                toggleButton.buttonName = 'add';
        };

        trackChanges = (index) => {
            return index;
        }
    }
```

I've tried placing ngIf (as shown in the code before ngFor) but is not that much effective.

Is there any way to load component when opening accordion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering to your question:

> Is there any way to load component when opening accordion?

Yes, there is, but I'm not sure it's gonna solve a lagging problem. Anyway, try to wrap the expansion panel's content in a `ng-template` containing the `matExpansionPanelContent` attribute. It'll lazy load its content (see [the docs](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview#lazy-rendering)).

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle="true" (click)="toggleTree($event, input)">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        <mat-icon>{{input.buttonName}}</mat-icon>
        {{input.key}}
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
      <ul class="main-obj">   // tried *ngIf here
        <div class="obj-list" *ngFor="let item of input.value; trackBy: trackChanges">
          <li>{{item.key}}: {{item.value}}</li>
          <li style="list-style: none; margin-left: -40px;">
            <app-tree [input]="item"></app-tree>
          </li>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: Thanks!!....It worked!... This also solved the lagging issue for bulk data as ng-template restricts the accordion to load data unless it is expanded. I'm grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I used for a tree like with over 8000 nodes for two level (so, nested loops) with checkboxes (select/unselect all) and filter for each level.

Before used ng-template was impossible to present it to client, was very slow.

But now it works fast with syntax:

```
<h2 class="mt-5">Tree</h2>
 
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-auto">
      <mat-checkbox [ngModel]="selectAll" (change)="onToggleAllNodes()">
        {{selectAll ? 'Unselect All': 'Select All'}}</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Filter top</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput #filterNodeinput (input)="onFilterByNodes(filterNodeinput.value)">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<mat-accordion togglePosition="before" multi>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let nodeParent of TREE_DATA" [disabled]="nodeParent.accesses.length === 0" [hideToggle]="nodeParent.accesses.length === 0">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
     
      <mat-panel-title>
        <mat-checkbox
              [checked]="nodeParent.selected"
              [indeterminate]="nodeParent.indeterminate"
              (change)="onClickParent(nodeParent)">
          </mat-checkbox>
        {{ nodeParent.name }} <span class="selected-items" *ngIf="nodesLength(nodeParent) > 0"> {{ nodesLength(nodeParent) }} {{ nodesLength(nodeParent) === 1 ? 'Item selected' : 'Items selected' }}</span>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
 
    <!--Child-->
    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent *ngIf="nodeParent?.accesses.length > 0">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Filter child</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput #filterChildinput>
      </mat-form-field>
   
      <ul *ngFor="let nodeChild of filterChild(nodeParent.accesses, filterChildinput.value)" style="margin-left: 50px;">
        <li>
          <mat-icon class="sensitive-icon" *ngIf="nodeChild.sensitive">report_problem</mat-icon>
          <mat-checkbox [checked]="nodeChild.selected" (change)="onClickChild(nodeChild)"></mat-checkbox>
          {{ nodeChild?.name }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-template>
    <!--End Child-->
 
  </mat-expansion-panel>
 

</mat-accordion>
```